# JsPDF Html module producing unusable PDFs [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to generate a **PDF** from a **React** component. In my scenario it is a **MaterialUI** table but it could be anything.
The problem I'm facing is not with generating the PDF but the produced PDF itself which is too **heavy** and **unusable**.

I have a function like this:

```
createPdf = async (html: HTMLElement, pdfName: string = "report.pdf") => {
    const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true);

    await doc.html(html, {
      margin: 10,
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.65
      },
    });
    doc.save(pdfName);
    return doc.output("blob");
  };
```

I insert an HTMLElement which is the DOM content for my **React component** and it generates the PDF correctly. However this pdf is very big and extremely slow to load. Mind that I have an **i9 with 32GB of RAM** and it easily takes 15secs to render one page of the pdf...

Initially it was generating a **150MB** pdf but then I set compressed to true and it's now around **600KB**. That changes the size but it didn't improve the performance somehow. I've tried multiple computers and browsers and I've tinkered with the options for html2canvas and nothing seems to fix this.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since PDFs can contain vector/heavily compressed data, the file size often doesn't represent the complexity/the time it takes to render. What's actually being saved inside this PDF?

Comment: @DBS basically a MaterialUI table with 9 columns and as many rows as you can fit one page, and text. At first it seems very basic

Comment: That's so weird... I just used the HTML function of jsPDF. It shouldn't be doing that. No wonder the browser has a hard time coping with that

Comment: Will do so. Thank you so much for your input, it already serves as PoC.

Comment: Already did, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem as you. And the problem seems to be in material-ui.
I passed all my components to pure html tags and the speed improved dramatically.
I recommend not using material-ui but building your components with pure html.